# What is the justification for the "physics approach" for integration?

Tags: integration, calculus

When I say the "physics approach" to integration, I mean considering tiny slices and taking the limit, such as when you find the total charge in a rod by considering tiny slices of length $dl$ and integrating $λ(l) * dl$, where the function $λ(l)$ is the linear charge density, over the entire length of the rod. Intuitively, I see why this should work - as $dl$ approaches 0, the charge density should approach a constant, so by summing up all of these infinitesimal lengths times their charge densities, you should get the total charge. However, is there a more thorough way to relate these ideas to the mathematical definition of integrals? I know integrals are defined as the limit of a sum, so I see why the "physics approach" to integration would be mathematically justified. Could someone provide a slightly more formal explanation for why you are allowed to take slices of physical objects like rods?

Comment: What you describe as the "physics approach" to integration 
is essentially the mathematical definition of the
[Riemann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral).
See this article how this is actually mathematically rigorous.

Answer (score 1):

Which parts of calculus are used where depends on the example, but the way physicists write may not make this obvious.

When we deduce a $1$-dimensional integral result of the form $z=\int_a^bydx$, we use the FTC together together with $z_x=y$. The RHS may be the definition of $y$, or may be a product computed by the chain rule. For example, $\lambda(x)$ is *defined* by $q=\int_{x_i}^{x_f}\lambda(x)dx$ along a rod, but an infinitesimal pressure $dp=\rho\vec{g}\cdot d\vec{l}$ requires a chain-rule proof that $\nabla p=\rho{\vec g}$.

Multiple integrals require a further insight. Suppose, for example, you compute the charge in a region by integrating a charge density, which in turn is a per-particle charge multiplied by the number density of relevant particles, or a sum over one such product per species. Your question in this case wants an explanation of reasoning such as

> If species $i$ has number density $n_i$, in any infinitesimal volume $d^3\vec{x}$ there are $n_id^3\vec{x}$ such particles each of charge $q_i$, for a total of $q_in_id^3\vec{x}$. Summing over all species in a volume $V$, $Q=\int_V\rho d^3\vec{x}$ with $\rho:=\sum_iq_in_i$ the total charge density.

A mathematician might prefer to say species $i$ contributes a charge $q_i\underbrace{\int_Vn_id^3\vec{x}}_\ast$, where $\ast$ is, by the *definition* of $n_i$, the number of such particles in $V$. By distributivity of $\times$ over $+$, the total charge is$$\sum_iq_i\int_Vn_id^3\vec{x}=\int_V\left(\sum_iq_in_i\right)d^3\vec{x}.$$(Thank goodness $q_i$ doesn't vary by location, or we'd have no choice but to motivate a $q_i$ factor in an integrand.)

Either way, our understanding has two components: the quantity of interest is a definite integral, and suitable reasoning determines its integrand. The physicist can achieve both at once by thinking in terms of *infinitesimal regions*, in which everything is a region size multiplied by a quantity assumed not to vary throughout it. (I say "region" because it might not be through physical space, but mathematically it doesn't matter.)

As @ThomasFritsch's comment notes, by Riemann integrals (or something more general if physicists ever need it) this is mathematically equivalent to any other approach.